# umbracoNaviHide doesn't work on new project

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

All my recent projects has implemented umbracoNaviHide inside a True/False property, and they all work just fine. In my 7.6.9 upgraded project, I simply cannot get a True/False value to work.

On my Master composition, I have a "Navigation" tab together with a True/False property. All my pages inherit through that composition.

When I do something like:

```
var menuItems = CurrentPage.Site().Children;

@foreach(var item in menuItems) {
    if(item.IsVisible()) {
        <!--show element-->
    }
}
```

It doesn't work. It should work, as it has in all my lastest projects. Here's what I've tried:

```
var menuItems = CurrentPage.Site().Children.Where("Visible");
var menuItems = CurrentPage.Site().Children.Where("umbracoNaviHide == false"); //setting this to true gives me no results
var menuItems = CurrentPage.Site().Children.Where(x => x.IsVisible());
var menuItems = CurrentPage.Site().Children.Where("randomProperty == false"); //or true

foreach(var item in menuItems) {
    if(!item.HasValue("umbracoNaviHide)) { <!-- show item --> }
    if(item.GetPropertyValue("umbracoNaviHide")) == "false") { <!-- show item --> }
}
```

I think that's all. I did update my ModelsBuilder. I did restart the project. I did remove the property and readd it. I basically tried everything, but it just won't work.

What on earth?

UPDATE: Check out this. This is soooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo weird:

```
@foreach(var item in menuItems) {
    <p>@item.GetPropertyValue("umbracoNaviHide") - @item.Name</p>
}
```

This gives me the following:

```
FALSE - Our offers
FALSE - Technology
TRUE - Projects
FALSE - About us
FALSE - Gallery
TRUE - Contact
```

However, this is how the `umbracoNaviHide` is setup in the backoffice:

```
Ticked - Our offers
Not ticked - Technology
Ticked - Projects
Not ticked - About us
Not ticked - Gallery
Ticked - Contact
```

How the flying hell is this possible?

Comment: So you wanted to list children which are not existing at all? :) You can always check for Children.Any(x => x.IsVisible()) or similar. So it's solved?

Comment: @MarcinZajkowski Uh no, I want to use the umbracoNaviHide to create my menu of elements that should show/hide depending on that property's value.

Comment: Can you try taking the children with .Children(x => x.IsVisible())?

Comment: @MarcinZajkowski `CurrentPage.Site().Children(x => x.IsVisible())` gives me the exact same result as everything else.

Comment: That's very weird. I will try to find some time and check it by myself. Will let you know!

Comment: @MarcinZajkowski Thank you so much! Make sure to check out 7.6.9 first. All of this is done on my Master document type, by the way. The Master has a template which has the `RenderBody()` and is where I also do the code.

Comment: @MarcinZajkowski Also updated my post with newly discovered data. This is so weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, everything's clear now :)

You're using ***dynamic*** objects and you're trying to treat them as ***IPublishedContent***. If they are not mapped correctly it behave weird and unpredictable.

As dynamic objects will be removed in the following Umbraco versions, I suggest to use strongly typed ***IPublishedContent*** objects or take advantage of **[ModelsBuilder](https://github.com/zpqrtbnk/Zbu.ModelsBuilder/wiki)** and operate on generated models of specific types.

My test code is below. Both versions works in my test 7.6.9 solution.

```
// Dynamic object version - will be deprecated - don't use!
//var visibleChildItems = CurrentPage.Site().Children.Where("Visible");

// Strongly Typed version - suggested
var visibleChildItems = Model.Content.Site().Children(x => x.IsVisible());

<ul>
    @foreach (var item in visibleChildItems)
    {
        <li>
            <a href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Hope it will solve your problem. If you'll be interested about operating through dynamic objects and how to get properties from them, check a little bit old, but still valid **Razor Cheetsheet for Umbraco**: https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/umbraco-v6-mvc-razor-cheatsheets.

Comment: I don't understand how you can write this as an answer. I clearly wrote as a comment, that it doesn't work for me. It's even listed in my many examples I've tried. I'm trying to treat them both as dynamic and IPublishedContent, as you can clearly see in my examples. I've tried both. If you need to make an answer, at least come up with something new..

Comment: I shared it as an answer to put code samples there. You must did something wrong somewhere else then. I'm not able to call Children.Where(x => ...) on dynamic object, so I don't know how you're doing it in your code. Same with extension methods for IPublishedContent called for dynamic objects in your example. Maybe something is wrong with your cache? Did you republish the whole website? It works as usual for me. I can share my code from this example if you want.

Comment: I did republish the entire site yes. Can you show me your document type and content node structure, please?

Comment: I've confirmed this myself now. I created a new project and it was exactly identical in terms of Document Types and content nodes. It worked perfectly. On the real project, I cannot access ANY properties from the composition Master Document Type at all.

Comment: At least you know where to further look at. Check if composition is correctly applied and what's inside of the IPublishedContent object when you're casting it in the loop. You can also try to manually map it to Master composition, but it's not recommended here I think. Check inherits on your views as well. Interesting debugging session ahead :)

Comment: I can't even access the properties (such as title or description) from my Master composition. According to the staff, they made some changes to composition between 7.6.6 and 7.6.9: https://our.umbraco.org/contribute/releases/compare?from=7.6.6&to=7.6.9

This is not longer a issue with umbracoNaviHide but with the composition.

Comment: Can you share the whole views code from your master and screenshot of your document type with composition applied? I think it's something minor what causing this issue as it just works and work done is around other areas. What type of ModelsBuilder mode you have in your project? Can you check and share model class here as well?

Comment: I'm using Dll ModelsBuilder. Here's the view if I remove the unnecessary HTML: https://pastebin.com/iDv3CZJq - Here is a screenshot of the Gallery document which inherits from the Master composition: https://i.imgur.com/XfjqUJg.png

Comment: Okay what the ffffffffffffffff is going on. Out of no where, everything started working. I kid you not. I haven't changed one line of code or anything. After trying to push my site to the Umbraco Cloud site, it worked on my local machine as well. I have never been more confused in my life.

Comment: Glad you sorted it, no matter how and why ;) I think it was storing some legacy data in the models or cache.

Comment: Yeah that's what I think as well. How damn weird is that, huh.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot leave a comment so I'll post this as an answer. I had the same issue. In my case I had the default value set to checked, which I assumed was true. I set the default to unchecked. I went to umbracoNaviHide and then checked the box and it worked perfectly for me. I do thank you for pointing me in the right direction.